# Differences between xcm-simulator and xcm-emulator

Tags: xcm, testing

I'm trying to have a deep understanding of the differences between [xcm-simulator](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/master/polkadot/xcm/xcm-simulator) and [xcm-emulator](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/tree/master/xcm/xcm-emulator).

I understand that xcm-emulator is "less mocked" than xcm-simulator. But because when using xcm-simulator we also configure chains runtimes is a bit unclear for me. Some project that I have checked it out only use xcm-simulator to test their xcm capabilities, I wonder why is that?

Initially, I assumed the XCM-emulator was better for using a "less mocked" tool, thus allowing for more reliable tests to be built.

I would like to include a test case in my parachain project that checks whether I can transfer a token to another parachain and then return it to my parachain. Which of the two tools is best for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer, for your use case is better to use XCM Emulator with the relay chain and parachains runtimes.

From the [XCM Docs](https://paritytech.github.io/xcm-docs/testing/index.html)
The `xcm-emulator` is a tool to emulate XCM program execution using pre-configured runtimes, including those used to run on live networks, such as Kusama, Polkadot, Statemine, etc. This allows for testing cross-chain message passing and verifying outcomes, weights, and side-effects.

While the the `xcm-simulator` is a tool to quickly test the execution of various XCM instructions against the xcm-executor.

If can want to go more in deep with both, I recommend check this video: [XCM Simulator & xcm-emulator for parachain integration testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJo9SO1CAEQ) tak

Comment: Thanks it makes sense. Although I am finding it very difficult to find projects that use xcm-emulator apart from Polkadot. Do you have any idea why this is the case? Perhaps it's simply because they prefer to use other tools like Chopsticks, which I find curious